# Injecting and calling custom knockout component in another component

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, knockoutjs

I am using 2 components for multi-select and select input fields.

Multiselect component -

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/multiselect',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Namespace_Modulename/js/selectoptions'
], function (_, uiRegistry, multiselect, modal,selectoptions) {
    'use strict';

    return multiselect.extend({

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            console.log(selectoptions.myNew());
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Select Component -

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        myNew: function () {
            console.log('In my new function');
        },
    });
});
```

I have injected `selectoptions` component in multi-select component and calling its `myNew` method onUpdate of multi-select. But I am getting below error.

```
selectoptions.myNew is not a function
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to call the function now using

```
selectoptions.prototype.myNew();
```

But still not getting why we need to use prototype here.

Comment: Are you solve this?

Comment: Your updated solution saved me

Answer (score 1):

try call the function use

```
selectoptions().myNew();
```